# Best column data type for JSON data in PostgreSQL < 9.2?

Tags: json, postgresql, serialization

I'm going to store records with arbitrary fields, and the custom ones will automatically go into a separate serialized field. I don't care that they're not searchable nor sortable.

I've chosen the JSON serialization format. What is the best column data type, provided I don't have the new `json` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying data type in 9.2 is TEXT, so you should be able to use that - see http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-2-highlight-json-data-type/